# Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession throw exception without unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, poco-libraries

I have 2 version of code:

```
    // HTTP.h
    class HTTP
    {
    private:
      //unique_ptr<HTTPClientSession> session;
      HTTPClientSession session;

      bool doRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest& request, const string& path, const string& content, string& responseBody);
    public:
      HTTP(const string& adress);
    }

    // HTTP.cpp

    HTTP::HTTP(const string& adress)
    {
      Poco::URI uri(
        adress.substr(0, 4) == "http" ? adress : "http://" + adress
      );
      //session = make_unique<HTTPClientSession>(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
      HTTPClientSession session{ uri.getHost(), uri.getPort() };
    }

    bool HTTP::doRequest(HTTPRequest& request, const string& path, const string& content, string& responseBody) {
      ...
      session.setTimeout(Timespan(5, 0));
      //std::ostream& requestStream = session->sendRequest(request);
      std::ostream& requestStream = session.sendRequest(request);
      ...
    }
```

If I use unique_ptr to create session object, like in commented code, everythings worls fine.

But if I use just simple variables, like in current version.
Then line

**session.sendRequest(request)**

throw exception **Connection refused**

I do not understand why?
Could you explein me please.

P.S. **request** it is simple HTTP GET request to static resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HTTP::HTTP(const string& adress)
{
  Poco::URI uri(
    adress.substr(0, 4) == "http" ? adress : "http://" + adress
  );

  HTTPClientSession session{ uri.getHost(), uri.getPort() };
}
```

The last line in this constructor creates a local variable named `session`, ... which gets immediately destroyed when the constructor returns, and has nothing to do with the class member of the same member.

So, when all is said and done, the `session` member of this class instance remains uninitialized. For comparison purposes:

```
session = HTTPClientSession{ uri.getHost(), uri.getPort() };
```

This would correctly initialize the class member, instead, as your obvious intent was. However, since HTTPClientSession does not have a usable assignment operator, your only option is to either continue using `unique_ptr`, or restructure the constructor so that it constructs the class member in its initializer list.

Comment: I understood the main idea, in my code "session" is local var, not a class member.

But when I tried initialize session like your wrote, I got error:

Error C2248 'Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession::operator =': cannot access private member declared in class 'Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession'

Comment: Then this means that this library does not support this functionality, and you must always use unique ptr. I'll update my answer.